# Get same data twice from manually polling an API(MUX)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, promise, next.js

I am using `MUX` api to manage my videos.

What I want: when I get a `ready` `asset`, store some data from `asset` in my Firestore database.

Basics, `asset` in `MUX` has several statuses. All I need is `ready` status. If making request from  `Video.Assets.get(upload.asset_id)`, it may return an asset which is not ready. I need a ready one. So I manually poll using while check like below.

```
const getReadyAssetPromise = async function (upload) {
  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
  };

  let asset = await Video.Assets.get(upload.asset_id);

  while (asset.status !== "ready") {
    console.log("in the while loop");
    await sleep(3000);
    asset = await Video.Assets.get(upload.asset_id);
  }

  return asset;
};
```

However, for each uploading, I always got the same `asset` twice which caused my database had same data twice.

[browser console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzRT.png)

Much appreciate your ideas.

Below is the full code.

```
const fetcher = (url) => {
  return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
};

const { Video } = new Mux(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MUX_TOKEN_ID,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MUX_TOKEN_SECRET
);


// manually poll the asset status to be ready, in the future could upgraded into webhook
const getReadyAssetPromise = async function (upload) {
  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
  };

  let asset = await Video.Assets.get(upload.asset_id);

  while (asset.status !== "ready") {
    console.log("in the while loop");
    await sleep(3000);
    asset = await Video.Assets.get(upload.asset_id);
  }

  return asset;
};

const UploadForm = () => {
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
  const [isPreparing, setIsPreparing] = useState(false);
  const [uploadId, setUploadId] = useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState("");

  const toast = useToast();

  const { data, error } = useSwr(
    () => (isPreparing ? `/api/upload/${uploadId}` : null),
    fetcher,
    { refreshInterval: 5000 }
  );

  const upload = data && data.upload;

  if (isUploading && upload && upload.asset_id) {
    console.log("has asset_id");
    const assetPromise = getReadyAssetPromise(upload);

    const colRef = collection(db, "Videos");

    assetPromise.then((asset) => {
      console.log("get asset");
      console.log(asset);
      addDoc(colRef, {
        description: description,
        tags: tags.split(","),
        title: title,
        duration: asset.duration,
        thumb_url: `https://image.mux.com/${asset.playback_ids[0].id}/thumbnail.png`,
        vid_asset_id: upload.asset_id,
        vid_playback_id: asset.playback_ids[0].id,
        vid_url: `https://stream.mux.com/${asset.playback_ids[0].id}.m3u8`, // playback url  : "https://stream.mux.com/{PLAYBACK_ID}.m3u8"
        vid_tier: "free",
        created_at: serverTimestamp()
      });

      setIsUploading(false);
      showToast();
    });
  }

  if (error) return <ErrorMessage message="Error fetching api" />;
  if (data && data.error) return <ErrorMessage message={data.error} />;

  const createUpload = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("entering createUpload");
      return fetch("/api/upload", {
        method: "POST"
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(({ id, url }) => {
          console.log("setting uploadId");
          setUploadId(id);
          return url;
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error in createUpload", e);
      setErrorMessage("Error creating upload");
    }
  };

  const showToast = () => {
    toast({
      title: "Video uploaded.",
      description: "Your video is uploaded successfully.",
      status: "success",
      duration: 1000,
      isClosable: true
    });
  };

  const startUpload = (evt) => {
    if (title === "") {
      alert("Video title cannot be empty");
      return;
    }

    setIsUploading(true);
    console.log("after title check:" + uploadId);
    // createUpload(options)
    // Returns an instance of UpChunk and begins uploading the specified File.
    const upChunk = UpChunk.createUpload({
      endpoint: createUpload,
      file: inputRef.current.files[0]
    });

    upChunk.on("error", (err) => {
      setErrorMessage(err.detail);
    });

    upChunk.on("progress", (progress) => {
      setProgress(Math.floor(progress.detail));
    });

    upChunk.on("success", () => {
      setIsPreparing(true);
    });
  };

  if (errorMessage) return <ErrorMessage message={errorMessage} />;

  return (
    <>
      {console.count("counter")}
      <div className="container">
        <Text mb="8px">Video Title</Text>
        <Textarea
          value={title}
          isDisabled={isUploading}
          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Your video title"
        />

        <Text mb="8px">Video Tags</Text>
        <Textarea
          value={tags}
          isDisabled={isUploading}
          onChange={(e) => setTags(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Please seperate with comma. Example: tag1,tag2,tag3"
        />

        <Text mb="8px">Video Description</Text>
        <Textarea
          value={description}
          isDisabled={isUploading}
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Your video description"
        />

        {isUploading ? (
          <>
            {isPreparing ? (
              <div>Preparing... and Pushing Video Data into Firestore</div>
            ) : (
              <div>Uploading...{progress ? `${progress}%` : ""}</div>
            )}
            <Spinner />
          </>
        ) : (
          <label>
            <Button type="button" onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>
              Select a video file
            </Button>
            <input
              type="file"
              onChange={startUpload}
              ref={inputRef}
              accept="video/*"
            />
          </label>
        )}
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        input {
          display: none;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the bug. I don't know why my previous code error. But I found a solution by **using useEffect**

```
 const assetId = upload && upload.asset_id;
  // only run when asset_id is done
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUploading && upload && upload.asset_id) {
      console.log("has asset_id");
      // const assetPromise = getReadyAssetPromise(upload);
      const colRef = collection(db, "Videos");

      getReadyAssetPromise(upload).then((asset) => {
        console.log("get asset");
        console.log(asset);
        addDoc(colRef, {
          description: description,
          tags: tags.split(","),
          title: title,
          duration: asset.duration,
          thumb_url: `https://image.mux.com/${asset.playback_ids[0].id}/thumbnail.png`,
          vid_asset_id: upload.asset_id,
          vid_playback_id: asset.playback_ids[0].id,
          vid_url: `https://stream.mux.com/${asset.playback_ids[0].id}.m3u8`, // playback url  : "https://stream.mux.com/{PLAYBACK_ID}.m3u8"
          vid_tier: "free",
          created_at: serverTimestamp()
        });

        setIsUploading(false);
        showToast();
      });
    }
  }, [assetId]);
```